# How to run a docker Image in ECR in ECS via Jenkins CD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run a docker container in `ECS`, I have already managed to push the Image to `ECR` via `Jenkins`. I am trying to do the next step which is running the image via Jenkins to ECS.

following is my jenkins file:

```
node{
        stage('SCM Checkout'){
         git branch : 'my-branch', credentialsId: 'git-credentials-for-jenkins', url: 'git-url'
        }
        stage('Build Docker Image'){
         sh 'docker build -t my-app:latest ./my-app'
        }
        stage('Push Docker Image to ECR'){
         def file = readFile('./my-app/Version')
         def version = file.trim()
         docker.withRegistry("XXXXXXXX.amazonaws.com", "aws-credentials"){
          docker.image("my-app").push(version)
         }
        }

        stage("Deploy") {
            // what to do here ?

        }
        }
```

my jenkins instance is on AWS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of ECS, `docker run` is not enough. You need the following to run container on AWS ECS.

- AWS ECS cluster
- ECR image
- Task definition
- IAM role for service
- Service

So you can automate the last four-step and better to create the first one manually or also not bad to make this automatic but this one-time creation in the life cycle.

You can check this [AWS offical documentation to work](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/) with ECS in jenkins.

[devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/)

Comment: thanks for the response and to let you know I already have all 5 of these steps done as well, I can't find a single example of the jenkins script integrating all these steps to run the image. what do you think ?

Comment: From step 2 to last one, all step is mentioned in the link